# Отправка письма с html кодом

Tags: python, email, java, c++

Я отправляю письма, содержимое которых html-фрагменты.  Как мне отправлять вместе с html кодом стили к нему? Стили находятся в отдельном файле. И, вообще, возможно ли такое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Поддержка css-стилей в email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

[Набор правил для вёрстки электронных писем](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/)

Используйте табличную вёрстку вместо блочной, изображения вместо блоков с фоновым изображением.
Подключать css-файлы нельзя, нужно все стили перенести в HTML-атрибут style.

Советую сначала переверстать тело письма, следуя правилам из второй ссылки, но используя css-файл, а затем воспользоваться [парсером](http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/styler/convert/), который преобразует HTML с внешним css в HTML с инлайновыми стилями (для этого стили из css-файла нужно определить в тег <style>, либо разместить в сети html с css и дать парсеру урл этой страницы).