# Отправка почты со стилями

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, интересует отправка почта со стилями, как это удобнее сделать? может есть для этого ресурсы которые регенерируют html письма, либо можно где почитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Забудьте про все, что вы знали!!! Делайте верстку так, словно html4/5 и не существует!!!
2. Забудьте про блочную верстку!!! Используйте только табличную.
3. ВСПОМНИТЕ, что есть также теги ,  и другие забытые - использовать только их!!!
4. Все, что находится в head'e - в основном вырезается - использовать только inline-стили.
5. Если нужен background - только цвет. Если нужна картинка - значит весь текст должен быть картинкой.
6. http://habrahabr.ru/post/106387/
7. [Вопрос про письма на ХэшКоде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83248/c-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-html-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC) - лучше всего это почитать, там те ссылки, которые я и искал

Вообще все зависит от клиента (почтовая прога либо web-интерфейс почтовика). GMAIL вроде как теперь разрешает вставку в качестве background'a картинок. Но это пока исключения, лучше делать почти для всего. А "почти все" почти ничего не поддерживает.

Кроме всего вышеперечисленного - добавьте все так же в стили в HEAD - что-то может и останется.

И еще - где-то читал, что проверять лучше в MS Outlook 2007 - там вообще все с письмами напутано (по сравнению с 2003 - 2003 еще хорошо работал)))). Если там все будет хорошо, то скорее всего и на остальных будет замечательно.

Comment: Еще ссылку не нашел про наши клиенты (в том числе и web-интерфейс типа яндекса либо майла).

Про картинки - у тега img есть атрибуты height и width - Их обязательно укажите, т.к. иногда блокируется картинка, и если что-то не указано, то она растягивается. Смотрится отвратительно - можете мне поверить уже занимался этим вопросом)

И еще про картинки - не забудьте указать цвет фона, похожий на основной цвет картинки и alt укажите. 1-пиксельные распорки лучше не указывать - в спам попадет.

Самый верный способ проверить - это отослать себе тестовые письма. И проверять на разынх клиентах.

Comment: И еще один совет - всего все равно не учтете, так что делайте для большинства.

Про аутлук уже писал - сначала в нем добейтесь нормального отображения, а затем уже проверяйте в других клиентах.

Для этого лучше ознакомиться с самыми распространенными почтовыми клиентами у предполагаемой аудитории.

Answer (score 0):

Как бы нужно отправлять html код и заголовок + в правильной кодировке
и письмо будет со стилями
для этого смотрите PHP функцию mail()

Comment: Это понятно, а сами стили то как прописывать? указать на них путь или тэгом <style></style> ?

Answer (score 0):

Могу лишь в ответ привести пример отправки письма через PHP функцию mail() с оформлением:

```
$mailtext = 'Тут текст вашего письма оформленный в HTML код как вариант в табличной верстке';
$headers="Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
$headers.="From: почта от кого@почта.ру\nX-Mailer: SuperMailer";
mail("тут почта кому@почта.ру","Заголовок письма",$mailtext,$headers);
```

При должном желании сделать свое письмо не составить труда. В качестве отправной точки можно взять присылаемые в рассылках письма и посмотреть в режиме просмотра исходного письма какой там HTML код оформление.

Comment: К сожалению, не увидел в вашем примере само оформление, где оно? может меня не правильно поняли? я хочу например цвета текста изменить, изменить фон текста и т.д., просматривать исходный код думаю не лучшая затея, почтовики ведь реплейсят все.

Comment: может нужно прописывать inline стили <i style="....">...</i>?Просто предположение

Answer (score 0):

**zloctb** абсолютно прав.. например, запихните всё письмо в один блок div, и пропишите ему стили: 
`<div style='text-align: center; color: blue;'>Текст письма<div>`